# npm WARN package.json for latest version

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

We are already using the latest version of angular ("@angular/core": "~8.2.5").

But when install, npm gives some warning about the module versions.
Please see the above console result :

```
npm WARN angular-pell@0.1.0 requires peer of @angular/common@^5.2.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-pell@0.1.0 reuqires peer of @angular/core@^5.2.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

What is about the npm warn?

Why npm provides some warns?

Answer (score -1):

Try runing npm audit:

```
npm audit fix
```